# Xamarin Profiler crashes the application from start

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin application developed with MVVM Cross and I'm trying to profile it.

However, as soon as the first screen appears the app crashes.

The Xamarin Profiler console close to the crash:

```
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311): Display 0 HWC layers:
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311):     type    |    handle    | flag |  format   |   source crop (l,t,r,b)    |         frame       | name 
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311): ------------+--------------+------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+------
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311):      Device | 0x7456253da0 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1080.0 2220.0 |    0    0 1080 2220 | com.myapp.mobile/myapp.Mob[...].Views.InitializationScreen[29425]#0
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311):      Device | 0x7455e49000 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0   67.0  429.0 | 1013  592 1080 1021 | com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbars[...]rservice.CocktailBarService[14111]#0
03-08 13:38:56.797 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311): 
03-08 13:38:56.798 D/Layer   ( 3311): [9c16bd7 StatusBar#0]::reparent oldParent:[Surface(name=9c16bd7 StatusBar)/@0xd24d4f6 - animation-leash#0], newParent:[WindowToken{4248f56 android.os.BinderProxy@79e2571}#0]
03-08 13:38:56.798 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3311): id=8714 Removed Surface(name=9c16bd7 StatusBar)/@0xd24d4f6 - animation-leash#0 (1/86)
03-08 13:38:56.798 I/StackScroller( 8301): ADJUST STACK.TRANSLATION
03-08 13:38:56.798 I/PanelView( 8301): n.B.P.E.C:false, false, false, false, false, false
03-08 13:38:56.806 I/Layer   ( 3311): id=8714 onRemoved Surface(name=9c16bd7 StatusBar)/@0xd24d4f6 - animation-leash#0 
03-08 13:38:56.806 I/StackScroller( 8301): ADJUST STACK.TRANSLATION
03-08 13:38:56.806 I/chatty  ( 8301): uid=10002(com.samsung.android.app.aodservice) com.android.systemui identical 1 line
03-08 13:38:56.807 I/StackScroller( 8301): ADJUST STACK.TRANSLATION
03-08 13:38:56.813 D/ViewRootImpl@6805198[InitializationScreen](29425): MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-08 13:38:56.847 E//system/bin/tombstoned( 3583): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
03-08 13:38:56.850 E/audit   ( 3433): type=1701 audit(1552045136.845:6051): auid=4294967295 uid=10403 gid=10403 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 pid=29425 comm=54687265616420506F6F6C20576F72 exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=6
03-08 13:38:56.861 I/BootReceiver( 3871): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-08 13:38:56.866 W/ActivityManager( 3871): crash : com.myapp.mobile,0
03-08 13:38:56.876 W/ActivityManager( 3871):   Force finishing activity com.myapp.mobile/myapp.Mobile.Droid.Views.InitializationScreen
```

Logcat output:

```
 2019-03-08 14:33:24.824 30618-30618/com.myapp.mobile D/Mono: Assembly Ref addref Plugin.CurrentActivity[0x7627f95300] -> Mono.Android[0x7627fb1700]: 26
2019-03-08 14:33:24.827 30618-30618/com.myapp.mobile A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 30618 (cmyapp.mobile), pid 30618 (cmyapp.mobile)
```

I've been at this for a long time but I cannot figure out why the Xamarin Profiler crashes my app. 
The app performs well in Debug/Release mode.

Comment: What version of plugin current activity do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they miss this step from their [Xamarin Profiler documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/index?tabs=windows) you should disable the **Use Shared Runtime** option in **Android Options** as they do suggest this in their [Profiling documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling).

This worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't it for me :(

Comment: On VS Enterprise 2022 Version 17.7.3, I don't even have that option. Profiler never even starts the app and just display the message: "[My_Application_Name] stopped".